# querying unidirectional @ManyToOne association from other side with querydsl-jpa

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I have a situation with a unidirectional @ManyToOne association which I need to query eagerly from the other side with querydsl-jpa (additional to grouping and calculating).

```
public class Skill implements java.io.Serializable {
  ...
  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  private Profile profile;

  private int level;
  ...
}
```

Now I'd like to get all Profiles sorted by the sum of their skill-levels *and* their Skills

```
final QProfile profile = QProfile.profile;
final QSkill skill = QSkill.skill;

return from(profile, skill)
  .where(skill.profile.eq(profile))
  .where(...)
  .groupBy(profile.id)
  .list(profile);
```

...will find the profiles correctly, but I need as well their skills (and their overall level).

My current workaround is to fetch all (skills and profiles) into a list of result-objects, then grouping skills to profiles and calculating their overall level

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Using OneToMany from Profile to Skill with mappedBy would be a solution here.

```
public class Profile {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile")
    private List<Skill> skills;
}
```

Comment: if it's lazy mapped and you don't provide an accessor for it, it might be acceptable